# lightning page/component redirection

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I have developed a **Lightning App** which included a component. Following is the Component screenshot, On click of **Register Button** its **Insert a new contact** and on click of **Already register** i want to **redirect to a new component name login.**

How to **redirect from one component to another component** in **lightning** salesforce ?

**Component -**

```
<aura:component >
<h1>Page Redirection Test</h1>
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="inputSample2">Email</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <ui:inputEmail aura:id="email" class="slds-input" placeholder="abcd@gmail.com" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slds-float--left">
    <ui:button aura:id="alreadyRegister" label="Already Register" class="slds-button slds-button--brand" press="{!c.navigateToMyComponent}"/>
</div>
```

**Controller JS**

```
({
navigateToMyComponent : function(component, event, helper) {
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
    evt.setParams({
        componentDef : "c:LightningLoginC",
        componentAttributes: {
            email : component.find("email").get("v.value")
        }
    });
    evt.fire();
}
```

})

APP -

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" implements="force:appHostable">
<!--<c:LightningLoginComp />-->
<c:LightningLoginC />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an [event](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_lightning_navigateToComponent.htm) which is BETA and you may want to experiment with same

```
navigateToMyComponent : function(component, event, helper) {
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
    evt.setParams({
        componentDef : "c:myComponent",
        componentAttributes: {
            contactName : component.get("v.contact.Name")
        }
    });
    evt.fire();
}
```

In the above code **componentDef** holds the component where you want to navigate

and you can pass attribute values as well as you move along using **componentAttributes**

Comment: I am getting the following error -
Action failed: c$LightningLoginComp$controller$navigateToMyComponent [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]

Comment: Are you inside lightning container or vf container ?

Comment: Also share the updated code you are trying

Comment: Following is my Button inside component - 
<div class="slds-float--left">
                        <ui:button aura:id="alreadyRegister" label="Already Register" class="slds-button slds-button--brand" press="{!c.navigateToMyComponent}"/>
                    </div>

Following is the Controller JS -

Comment: navigateToMyComponent : function(component, event, helper)  {
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:LightningLoginC");
        evt.setParams({
            componentDef : "c:LightningLoginC",
            componentAttributes: {
                contactName : component.find("email").get("v.value")
            }
        });
        evt.fire();
    }

CONTROLLER JS CODE

Comment: Replace e.force: LightningLoginC with e.force:NavigateToComponent and should work

Comment: No its not working getting the following error again - 
Action failed: c$LightningLoginComp$controller$navigateToMyComponent
Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined

Comment: Sorry n is small in navigate . JavaScript is case sensitive

Comment: Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined.
Not Working after making n in small caps,

Comment: Add the latest code to the question please .Thanks

Comment: m i missing something else ?

Comment: Code Added to Question

Comment: Are you able to log the event ? Also I do not see any attributes you have defined .use console.log to figure if the event is missing

Comment: I have added a log after - 
var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        console.log(evt);
Result is - Undefined

Comment: What's the version of your lightning component metadata ?Is it 37 ?What IDE are you using to create these components

Comment: How can i check this lightning component metadata ? I am writing all this code in Developer Console and testing in browser

Comment: you might also need to add: <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToComponent" type="EVENT"/>  to the component

Comment: @LukeInman-Semerau
its not giving any error in UI and Console, But it's not redirecting to another component.